# Display Map Marker which is randomly picked?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

When i getting `latlng` from a another page which generate `latlng` from the address, the markers can be displayed. But when I getting the `latlng` from a page which generate `latlng` from a random pickup, all the markers did not shows up. Is it normal or, my own mistakes? thank you in advance.

I store the `latlng` in the sqlserver. so, these are the code.

these are backend code.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connstr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select title=city,lat=latitude,lng=longitude,description from googleMap", con))
            {
                con.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                da.Fill(dt);
                System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
                List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
                Dictionary<string, object> row;
                foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
                    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
                    }
                    rows.Add(row);
                }
                return serializer.Serialize(rows);
```

these are the javascript.

```
 function initialize() {
    var markers = JSON.parse('<%=ConvertDataTabletoString() %>');
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(markers[0].lat, markers[0].lng),
        zoom: 4,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        //  marker:true
    };
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
        var data = markers[i]
        var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: data.title
        });
        (function (marker, data) {

            // Attaching a click event to the current marker
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
                infoWindow.setContent(data.description);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            });
        })(marker, data);
    }
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: How does the output of ConvertDataTabletoString() look like?

Comment: `[{"title":"city","lat":3.056830,"lng":101.591930,"description":"desc"},{"title":"city","lat":3.060510,"lng":101.580370,"description":"desc"},{"title":"city","lat":2.204630,"lng":102.245970,"description":"desc"},{"title":"city","lat":1.552420,"lng":103.633180,"description":"desc"},{"title":"city","lat":3.835490,"lng":103.350340,"description":"desc"},{"title":"city","lat":3.835491,"lng":103.350340,"description":null}]`

Comment: these are just dummy and the entire `latlng` generated from searching the address first except the last `latlng`. hope its help